# Javascript display name of div

Tags: javascript

I have a container with divs inside, using Javascript I am trying to open an alert box for each item found displaying the 'name' of the div...

```js
items = document.getElementsByClassName("single_item");

for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    alert("This is an item - the name is...")
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div name="item1" class="single_item">
        Item 1
    </div>
    <div name="item2" class="single_item">
        Item 2
    </div>
    <div name="item3" class="single_item">
        Item 3
    </div>
    <div name="item4" class="single_item">
        Item 4
    </div>
</div>
```

I am stuck trying to access the name value, anyone have an example I can look at?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.getAttribute()` to do this. Also, have a habit of using `var` keyword for your variables, or further, when your code gets bigger, you might end up having a lot of global variables.

Also, you are using `name` attribute, which is used for form elements like `input`, so if you want to use it for your `div`, you can use custom attributes like `data-name` and accordingly edit your JS getAttribute value

```js
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("single_item");

for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    //using getAttribute to fetch the name attribute value
    alert("This is an item - the name is..." + items[i].getAttribute("name"));
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div name="item1" class="single_item">
        Item 1
    </div>
    <div name="item2" class="single_item">
        Item 2
    </div>
    <div name="item3" class="single_item">
        Item 3
    </div>
    <div name="item4" class="single_item">
        Item 4
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Also, am just curious to know why you are using `alert()` which is quite annoying and not recommended. If you are trying to debug and want to output some results, you can always use `console.log()` which will print the results in your console, and unlike `alert()`, it won't stop executing your JS either.

Answer (score 1):

```js
items = document.getElementsByClassName("single_item");

for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    alert("This is an item - the name = " + items[i].getAttribute("name"))
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div name="item1" class="single_item">
        Item 1
    </div>
    <div name="item2" class="single_item">
        Item 2
    </div>
    <div name="item3" class="single_item">
        Item 3
    </div>
    <div name="item4" class="single_item">
        Item 4
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `name` is not a valid attribute of `div` element. Instead, `data-name` should be used.

Answer (score 1):

do it like this, with getAttribute

```js
items = document.getElementsByClassName("single_item");

for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    alert("This is an item - the name is " + items[i].getAttribute("name"));
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div name="item1" class="single_item">
        Item 1
    </div>
    <div name="item2" class="single_item">
        Item 2
    </div>
    <div name="item3" class="single_item">
        Item 3
    </div>
    <div name="item4" class="single_item">
        Item 4
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Following code

```
for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var nameValue = item[i].getAttribute('name');
    alert("This is an item - the name is " + nameValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If by name you mean the text inside the div, then this is accessible via textContent property

```
alert("This is an item - the name is "+items[i].textContent);
```